# NodeJs text file writing

Tags: node.js, file-handling

I am trying to write a text file from NodeJs. I have server running on my laptop. Currently, i am running client on my laptop and it works fine. But if i run same NodeJs client on Linux running on raspberrypi, it doesn't write on file or neither it gives any error.
I have the following code for client

```
 var ioC = require('socket.io-client'),
     ioClient = ioC.connect('http://localhost:4000'),
     fs = require('fs'),
     os = require('os');

 ioClient.on('connect', function () { console.log("socket connected"); });

 ioClient.on('ChangeState', function(msg){
             console.log(msg);
             fs.writeFile('server.txt', JSON.stringify(msg), function (err){
             if (err) return console.log(err);
             });
});
```

Can anybody please help me what can be the issue with this?

Comment: Maybe the process doesn't have the rights to write to that file? Check you file permissions. Ps. you said it worked on your laptop, but not what OS your laptop was running.

Comment: My laptop is running Windows 7. Can you please help how to set file permissions on linux?

Comment: The easiest would be to run `chmod 777 .` on the folder your running the script from.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting to localhost which won't work if the client is on a different machine. You need to change the server to listen to the ip address your server has in your network, and also need to let your client connect to this ip. You can get the ip by running `ifconfig` in your terminal. Then (depending on wireless or wired connection) look for something like (usually the last paragraph):

[image]

and create the server on this ip. E.g.

```
192.168.178.30:4000
```

and connect to the same address from your client.

To find your ip on windows, [refer to this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-computers-ip-address#1TC=windows-7)